# Git clone from remote ssh repository - change the machine on the remote network before executing the clone command

Tags: git, proxy, ssh, git-clone

I'd like to clone a git repository from my company's servers to my personal computer. The only way to acces these servers from "outside" is by logging in per ssh to 'machine1'

```
ssh user@machine1.company.xy
```

Unfortunately, git ist not installed on that specific machine. So a git clone like

```
git clone ssh://user@machine1.company.xy/path/to/repo <local-repo-path>
```

won't work. What I would have to do is to change to another machine 'machine2' where git is installed after having logged in to the network via 'machine1'. So to get the clone working I would have to execute a command like

```
ssh machine2
```

before actually executing the git command. Is there any way to do that? Something like a pre-clone hook maybe?

Is it possible to somehow pack the remote repository into a file (patch?), to copy that file onto the local machine and to clone from that file?

Looking forward to your hints and suggestions!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this by configuring a ssh proxy command. Note: this assumes [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) is available on the proxy server; you can replace netcat with a similar script in perl or whatever if needed.

Add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`, creating it if needed:

```
Host machine1
User yourusername
HostName machine1.yourcompany.com

Host machine2
User yourusername
ProxyCommand ssh machine1 nc %h %p
HostName machine2.internal.network
```

Now you can `ssh machine2` and it will automatically tunnel through machine1. This means using git is as simple as `git clone ssh://machine2/path`.

It is also possible to bundle the repository into a single file, using the [`git bundle`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html) command. This shouldn't be necessary with a proper ssh proxy setup though.

Comment: This sounds like a great solution. Unfortunately, netcat obviously doesn't exit on the remote machine. It's a sparc architecture running SunOS 10. Is there an alternative to netcat I could possibly use?

Comment: The only requirement is you put together some simple program that'll relay from stdin/stdout to some arbitrary remote host; you can probably throw together some simple script in whatever scripting languages are available there, or compile netcat or socat or something and put them in your home directory

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Seems like a challenge to me, but I'll try my best. Thanks again!