# Redirecting stdin/stdout to/from a remote host via ssh

Tags: perl, proxy, ssh, redirect

I'm trying to write a perl script that redirects its stdin to a remote machine and at the same time redirects the stdout of the remote machine to its stdout:

```
callingProgram <--> myScript <--> sshTunnelToRemote
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769986/git-clone-from-remote-ssh-repository-change-the-machine-on-the-remote-network-b) and bdonlan's answer for the purpose of the script.

First I tried to use the `open2()` function from the IPC library but for reasons described [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Bidirectional-Communication-with-Another-Process) it doesn't seem to be a good approach, I didn't even get a simple `grep` command working.

My second idea was to use the `Net::SSH::Perl` or the `Expect` libraries but they're not available on the machine where the script is supposed to be executed and I can't install libraries there.

So my question is what could be a simple way to achieve what I want? Solutions using [ba]sh or even C++ are also possible. The targeted platform is Solaris 10.

Comment: Explain the reason why/what makes you think you "can't install libraries there".

Comment: I have tried it. The installer tried to create files at locations where I don't have write permission and therefore failed.

Comment: Tunnels are for sockets. open2 doesn't create sockets. You want to create a socket, connect it to the tunnel, then dup that socket unto STDIN and STDOUT.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you could probably get away with nothing more than `system()` — don't *pass the data* from your stdin to ssh's stdin and from your stdout to ssh's stdout; just let ssh *inherit* your stdin and stdout. Unless you need to modify the data in transit somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I implement this inheritance?

Comment: @Deve by doing nothing and calling `system("ssh", "remotehost", "somecommand")`.

Comment: Hm, I don't know if I got your idea. What would `somecommand` be? It's unknown when calling the script. I think I'll install a newer version of ssh that supports the `-W` option.

Answer (score 0):

[cpanminus can do this for you](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.4004/lib/App/cpanminus.pm#Where_does_this_install_modules_to?_Do_I_need_root_access?)

Running:

```
cd ~/bin
curl -LO http://xrl.us/cpanm
chmod +x cpanm
```

Now you can try your problem using the right tools (e.g. `Net::SSH::Perl`).

The power of perl is cpan, and cpanminus gives you the ability to install whatever you need even if you don't have permission to install to the system-wide libraries.

Read [the module documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.4004/lib/App/cpanminus.pm) for the full details.