# Git, SSH and ProxyCommand

Tags: git, ssh, proxy

I have a git server that is behind a firewall. I can access the firewall from my home, but not the git server. However, I can access the git server from the firewall (that is, I can SSH to the firewall and then SSH from the firewall to the git server). I am looking to push and pull to the git repos from my home machine, and I thought the SSH ProxyCommand would do it. So I added the following to my SSH config file:

```
Host git_server
 HostName git_server.dom
 User user_git_server
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 ProxyCommand ssh firewall exec nc %h %p

Host firewall
 HostName firewall.dom
 User user_firewall
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

With this setup, I can directly SSH to the git server by doing `ssh git_server`. However, git commands that need to talk to the server do not work. `git remote show origin` fails with the message:

```
ssh: connect to host git_server.dom port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

The url of the origin repo is

```
ssh://user_git_server@git_server.dom/path/to/bare/repository/repo.git
```

I think I have most of the things in place, but am missing a small crucial piece. Any pointers to what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ssh://user_git_server@git_server.dom/path/to/bare/repository/repo.git
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You are using the wrong URL for your repository. Since your ssh config file has a host entry for `git_server` you need to use that host name in your repository URL as well, otherwise SSH will not use a ProxyCommand.

The correct URL should be either

```
ssh://user_git_server@git_server/path/to/bare/repository/repo.git
```

or simply

```
user_git_server@git_server:/path/to/bare/repository/repo.git
```

Comment: Nope, that could work too. It is a [ssh-uri](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9835653/6309), ie a non-[scp syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14134674/6309) which wouldn't use the `~/.ssh/config` file. And if you were to use the [scp syntax](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) as you recommend, you wouldn't need to specify the user name: `ssh://git_server:/path/to/bare/repository/repo.git`. And you meant ['colon'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29), not 'color' ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly it is that made you say "Nope". When will a ssh-uri NOT use the ssh-config file?

Comment: Ah. Tested this and the colon has to go.

Comment: I meant "Nope, the OP isn't using the wrong url, just a different syntax which would not take advantage of the ssh config file".

Comment: Well, in that case it seems you're wrong. At least my ssh doesn't care about the syntax and will always use my configure file.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, as mentioned in "[Git clone from remote ssh repository - change the machine on the remote network before executing the clone command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770162/6309)", that you don't have the command [`netcat`](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) on the proxy server.

You have also [another solution with `socat`](http://gitolite.com/git-over-proxy.html),  which will negotiate with the HTTP(S) proxy server using the CONNECT method to get you a clean pipe to the server on the far side. See [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).

```
host gh
    user git
    hostname github.com
    port 22
    proxycommand socat - PROXY:your.proxy.ip:%h:%p,proxyport=3128,proxyauth=user:pwd
```

> Now you can just say (for example):

```
git clone gh:sitaramc/git-notes.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `connect-proxy` and `socat` don't work on my side, but `ncat` does.

Here it is: `ProxyCommand ncat --proxy-type http --proxy <ip>:<port> %h %p`.